# How to make Outlook go to 0 unread mails when I have clicked on the very last one?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Say, if Outlook indicates that I have 3 unread emails, and I clicked on each one to read it.

Then I went to other apps (on the Mac).  And Outlook would still show I have 1 unread email, which is the last one I clicked on already.  I had to click on any other email to make the count go to 0.

Is there a way that I can make Outlook count it as "already read" after I clicked on it?

Comment: Did any of the below answers help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal behavior for Outlook. However, you can change a setting that will auto-read the email once it's been opened. To do this:

1. Open Outlook and go to File > Options > Mail.
2. Click on "Reading Pane..." - which is under the Outlook panes heading.
3. Tick "Mark items as read when viewed in the Reading Pane" and set it to 0 seconds.

This will automatically set the email to read when it's opened in the preview pane.

Comment: nobody is using a Mac!

Answer (score 1):

Outlook will go to 0 when all emails have been read (clicked on for the Reading Pane; or otherwise opened).  This is default Outlook behavior.

If you have done all the above, look through your folder list. Sometimes emails get moved to a folder before being read and that causes what you see above.

Try the suggestions to see if they help you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a somewhat annoying "feature" of Outlook. Thankfully, Microsoft has some good documentation on how to make it so viewing an email immediately sets it as read. [View this Microsoft article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/mark-a-message-as-read-or-unread-59b44298-08c2-4eb7-8128-ea0fb7f52720) and look under "Change how quickly messages are marked as read".

Comment: I clicked on it and the assumption is I have not read it? I must say Outlook has a doubting personality

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the suggestion of NiallUK to go to File > Options > Mail > Reading pane > Check "Mark items as read when viewed in the Reading Pane" and set it to 0 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Let me add an answer for the Mac:

Outlook ➜ Preferences ➜ Reading ➜ When viewed in the reading pane for 0 seconds